# do / while loop inside a error

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to read a user input using the following -
getting an error at the while session that variable 'n'- can not find simple -variable n.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    do{

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
        System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
        int n = reader.nextInt(); // Scans the next token of the input as an int.

        switch(n){
            case 1: System.out.println("load_flight1()");
                break;
            case 2: System.out.println("load_flight2()");
                break;
            case 3: System.out.println("load_flight3()");
                break;
            case 4: System.out.println("generate_report()");
                break;
            case 5: System.out.println("exit()");
                break;
            default: System.out.println("Invalid menu choice");
                     System.out.println("press any key:");
         }
    }while ((n!=1) && (n!=2) && (n!=3) && (n!=4) && (n!=5));
```

Can somebody spot where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: your `int n = reader.nextInt();` is invisible outside of the scope. Introduce local variable `n` before do loop.

Comment: n is actually out of scope....

Comment: Not really related to the described problem, but don't create Scanner in each iteration. Declare and create one scanner before your loop and use it inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Scope of `n` is inside of the `do ... while Loop` where the condition is not part of the Loop.
Declare it outside of the loop.

```
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); // Reading from System.in
    System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
int n;
do {
    n = reader.nextInt();  
    switch (n) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("load_flight1()");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("load_flight2()");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("load_flight3()");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("generate_report()");
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("exit()");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid menu choice");
        System.out.println("press any key:");
    }

} while ((n != 1) && (n != 2) && (n != 3) && (n != 4) && (n != 5));
```

Comment: `n = reader.nextInt();` should  be done in while loop

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul It is done in the while loop

Comment: You are reading a value that won't be analyzed in the switch like this ;)